# Declare Nodejs global variables in "before" hook in WebdriverIO using TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, webdriver-io

I'm trying to port my JS WDIO project ot TypeScript

I have faced the issue when during the development TypeScript is not recognizing my Nodejs global variables declared in `before` hook in my WDIO config:

```
...
let chai = require('chai');
...
before: async function (capabilities, specs) {
        //setting global variables
        global.foo = "bar"
        global.expect= chai.expect;
        global.helpers = require("../helpers/helpers");
        // ... etc.
        // ... etc.
    },
```

I came across different SO topics but seems like they are not relevant since the approach here is bit different (because of the `before` hook)...

I even have manged to get it working at some point by creating global.d.ts with something inside like:

```
declare module NodeJS {
    interface Global {
        foo: string
    }
}
```

But after this typescript stopped recognizing WDIO types lik `browser`, `$` etc.
And also with this approach I had to use `global.foo` in my tests meaning I have to change hundreds of occurrences of `foo`.

How can I migrate my project to TypeScript and continue using my global variables from the `before` hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to augment both the `NodeJS.Global` interface and global scope

Your `global.d.ts` will look like this

```
import chai from "chai";

// we need to wrap our global declarations in a `declare global` block
// because importing chai makes this file a module.
// declare global modifies the global scope from within a module
declare global {
  const foo: string;
  const expect: typeof chai.expect;
  const helpers: typeof import("../helpers/helpers");

  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      foo: typeof foo;
      expect: typeof expect;
      helpers: typeof helpers;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I declared the actual globals `const` because you only set them by referencing `global` in your `before` hook.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out and will give you a feedback before bounty ends

Comment: would you be so kind to take a look on my new question. Your approach helped my a lot. However I'm stuck where I need to "do some statements" before declaring the type of the global variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847229/declare-chai-custom-plugin-as-a-nodejs-global-variable-in-typescript

Comment: Yes, I will take a look.